# Python Request returning different result than original page (browser)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to do a simple WebScrapper to monitor Nike's site here in Brazil.
Basically i want to track products that have stock right now, to check when new products are added.

My problem is that when i navigate to the site https://www.nike.com.br/snkrs#estoque I see different products compared to what I see using python requests method.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers ={
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.nike.com.br/snkrs#estoque'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

len(soup.find_all(class_='produto produto--comprar'))
```

This code gives me 40, but using the browser I can see 56 products https://prnt.sc/26jeo1i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data comes from a different source, within 3 pages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers ={
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
}

productList = []
for p in [1,2,3]:
    url = f'https://www.nike.com.br/Snkrs/Estoque?p={p}&demanda=true'

    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    
    productList += soup.find_all(class_='produto produto--comprar')
```

**Output:**

```
print(len(productList))
56
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out ! But.. how did you managed to see the data comes from this other page?

Comment: Go to the Dev Tools (shft-ctrl-i). Look at Network -> XHR. And see if you can find the data within those requests. You might need to refresh the page after opening Dev Tools